# If i have rpcuser and rpcpassword of a remote bitcoin server,can i transfer that server's bitcoin to other address?

Tags: bitcoind, wallet-security

I don't know if this can be done.
Thanks!

Comment: `rpcallowip` should be used to only accept trusted outside connections, otherwise DoS and brute force vulnerabilities would be possible if only rpcuser and rpcpassword were required. Thankfully, the default is to only allow from localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is allowing remote connections to the rpc port (usually 8332) and they have `rpcallowip` set so that your IP address is allowed (e.g. it's set to 0.0.0.0/0), then yes, you can connect to the server and transfer all of the Bitcoin from the server to an address.

Comment: Thank you!~  could you give some advice about secure wallet server?

Comment: Use a firewall to only allow connections to the rpcport and to your ssh port from specific IP addresses. Make sure that the only other ports that are open and accessible from outside are the ports for services you are actually providing. Then use `-rpcallowip` to allow only your IP address(es) to access the RPC server. This way you have two layers of protection against attempts to get into the RPC server. You should also secure your ssh by using only ssh key authentication. Don't use passwords.